# What is causing this? Lexical error at line 39, column 85. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : ""

Tags: python

Hello trying to insert a panda dataframe  into SQL Server 2017 and I'm getting this

```
Lexical error at line 39, column 85.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : ""
```

at this point

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.someTable([records], [id], [userid], [originid],
[targetid],[targetname], [start_date], [end_date],[next_offset], [set_id])                
values (?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?)",  
row['records'], row['id'],row['userid'], row['usernanme'], 
row['originid'], row['targetid'], row['targetname'],
row['start_date'], row['end_date'], row['next_offset'], row['set_id'])
```

The rest seems ok... As far as I can tell this is correct? What Am I doing wrong? Thnks

Comment: [Pythonic way to create a long multi-line string](//stackoverflow.com/q/10660435)

Answer (score 2):

Reformat your string like so:

```
cursor.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO dbo.someTable([records],
    [id], [userid], [originid], [targetid], [targetname],
    [start_date], [end_date], [next_offset], [set_id])
    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """,
    (row['records'], row['id'], row['userid'], row['usernanme'],
    row['originid'], row['targetid'], row['targetname'],
    row['start_date'], row['end_date'], row['next_offset'], row['set_id']))
```

Also, it seems you are missing parentheses around your parameters.

Comment: Now its giving me "EOL While scanning string literal"  How do you escape these things? there seems to be no information on this?

Comment: It shouldn't. Make sure you are only using 3 quotation marks (an extra quotation will cause this error) @RobD

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a line break that your code is not recognizing, It is different between unix and windows. "\r\n" is for windows/DOS vs "\n" is on unix vs "\r" is on mac. Something created on windows/DOS is passed to unix will have problem.